# jQuery .hide() is not a Function Error when Called in setInterval Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to create a very simple slideshow using jQuery. Unfortunately, I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).get(...).hide is not a function
```

I have looked around Stack Overflow but could not find my answer. Originally, I had the functions called in setTimeout and setInterval defined outside $(document).ready() because I thought it made the code a little cleaner. However, after doing some research on the error, it seemed as if might have been an issuewith the code being outside $(document).ready(). However, placing it inside the $(document).ready() function did not resolve the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slideCount = 0;
    var currentSlide = 0;

    $("#slideshow").hide();

    var sliderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/ShowSlideshow",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    $("#slideshow").html(data);
                    $("#slideshow").show();
                    $("#slideshow .slide").not(":first-child").hide();
                    slideCount = $("#slideshow .slide").length;

                    setInterval(function () {

                        alert($("#slideshow .slide").get(currentSlide));
                        $("#slideshow .slide").get(currentSlide).hide();


                        if (!(currentSlide >= slideCount)) {
                            $("#slideshow .slide").get(parseInt(currentSlide + 1)).show();
                            currentSlide++;
                        } else {
                            $("#slideshow .slide").get(0).show();
                            currentSlide = 0;
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            },

            error: function (x, stat, er) {
                alert("Error " + stat + " " + er);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);

});
```

The data from the ajax request is returned fine. It also executes the following lines correctly:

```
    $("#slideshow").show();
                $("#slideshow .slide").not(":first-child").hide();
```

It is only when it enters the setInterval function that a problem arises. It is finding the elements fine (as indicated by the                       `alert($("#slideshow .slide").get(currentSlide));`statement) just not hiding it.

The following produces the same error:

```
    function displaySlideshow() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/ShowSlideshow",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $("#slideshow").html(data);
                $("#slideshow").show();
                $("#slideshow .slide").not(":first-child").hide();
                slideCount = $("#slideshow .slide").length;

                setInterval(slide, 5000);
            }
        },
        error: function (x, stat, er) {
            alert("Error " + stat + " " + er);
        }
    });
}

function slide () {

    alert($("#slideshow .slide").get(currentSlide));
    $("#slideshow .slide").get(currentSlide).hide();


    if (!(currentSlide >= slideCount)) {
        $("#slideshow .slide").get(parseInt(currentSlide + 1)).show();
        currentSlide++;
    } else {
        $("#slideshow .slide").get(0).show();
        currentSlide = 0;
    }
}   


$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#slideshow").hide();

    var sliderTimeout = setTimeout(displaySlideshow, 5000);



});
```

I have tried placing the setInterval function outside the ajax success callback (but within setTimeout) but still without success.

I have made an effort to find an answer, but have not yet been successful. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `.get()` returns an element from the jQuery object, and normal DOM nodes don't have a `.hide()` method - that's a jQuery API.

Comment: [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) - _"Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object."_...

Comment: In addition to @Pointy 's correct comment, if you want the first one, use `.first()` / `:first` or `.eq()` / `:eq()` for any other.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking get() was a jQuery method (and one just used [] to access DOM elements in plain JavaScript). What is the difference between using .get(index) vs [index] on DOM elements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

`$($("#slideshow .slide").get(currentSlide)).hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `get()`, which others have pointed out returns the actual DOM node, reduce the jQuery collection to the one element you want:

`$("#slideshow .slide").filter(":eq(" + currentSlide + ")").hide();`

In your case, you can even shorten it to:

`$("#slideshow .slide:eq(" + currentSlide + ")").hide();`